# How to set defaultLocale with i18n and angular-localization?

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework, internationalization

I need a help!  I tried to change a defaultLocale in my controller.js and I'am using i18n with angular. The strutucture is:

```
angular.module('starter.controllers', ['ngLocalize', 'ngLocalize.Config'])
.value('localeConf', {
    basePath: 'js/Locales',
    defaultLocale: 'pt-BR',
    sharedDictionary: 'common',
    fileExtension: '.lang.json',  
    ...
```

the directive:

```
.controller('ConfiguracaoCtrl', function ($scope,... , locale, localeConf) {...
```

and the function:

```
$scope.selecionaIdioma = function(idioma){


        localeConf.defaultLocale = idioma; //tried to set a language
        localStorage.setItem("appIdioma",idioma);

    }
```

I have the file to translate the languages: js > locales >  es-CL > common.lang.json                                                                                                and js > locales > pt-BR > common.lang.json

The "defaultLocale" changed but not the language. Please, any idea what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: A point.. in my app.js.. I have too:

    angular.module('starter', ['ionic', .., 'ngLocalize', 'ngLocalize.Config'])
 .value('localeConf', {
        basePath: 'js/Locales',
        defaultLocale: 'pt-BR',
        sharedDictionary: 'common',
        fileExtension: '.lang.json', ...


 The "select language" is in my controller.js.. So I need set "defaultLocale" in my app.js. Is this posible?

Answer (score 1):

You could use ngStorage: https://github.com/gsklee/ngStorage

Include the lib in your app: `angular.module('app', ['ngStorage']).`
Then use in your controller with, inject in your controller as: `$localStorage`

Then you can use `$localStorage.lanaguage = 'something'`

And get the info again with: `$scope.language = $localStorage.language`

Answer (score 0):

I got as follows..

I declared a global variable:

```
var idioma = window.localStorage.appIdioma;
```

and setted:
    ...

```
defaultLocale: idioma,
```

worked for me.

Comment: I'm really sorry. But I think you could do it better. This is not the good way of do the things. You shouldn't use window.localStorage. It's not  the angular way.